# How do I link/join/relate the types of two class fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, narrowing, type-narrowing

How do I get TypeScript to recognize that the value of one field in a class restricts the type of another?

Example code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG9oAcCuAnLAKAlCgPQBUAdBSUQL7TUBQokMAIgPYDmK0ARmFgGsCxcpRp16ASwB2CAKZYAZmGBzoAFQCeaOQFkwaFPQCQwRAC44iANwmAJp0vsOthkyjQACnIQAeWNByAB7y0nYwAnKabIoa2noGAHxGpmwAtmls0gByYGlylrC2xmDSkmlgIJZaOvpoANqwALrFwFkQCFgYwAhseG0ZWbn50IUANNCl5ZXV8XWNTYTIJsYIABaSEGQDmTl5agC80DtD+8XGpCtERCxYbGhoMlzramj8+-JYk2HQnZpPvzYxywckQahe0DYPAAVnIetA1go1A45BBpAByJAAdz6AnMK0kilwJz2IwO5Og6LMCHRSxWqw2WymFRA0CO0jkWKsCAI51o1woZCuRF4cLAGAgahqanR8Bp0E20GkbCQzEkHGkYB4IHBQIQ8UpcugADJoM50ULjMYqCt1psyMzKmzvtMQMUGMYKpEAMpsDBhYTLK2E3B2rYk4aHClUxC0lJW64AURwfUsYYdZRZCpgMV+BtliGgAB8zZx0RNlUhNSmsXI7IDuZMYGt7nXLVaQQhsNJfoyM66yJgcLyVrQ5CBJQrYqG+xH9mzow4OHGgwmiMm7lg033HazFbn9TpDYWS+aKyqlfw7rX671S1xIAjW3Z28ZO93e-bd2Q+IIR1aPQYBggA)):

```js
class Cat { purr() {/*...*/} }
class Dog { bark() {/*...*/} }
interface TypeMap {
    cat: Cat;
    dog: Dog;
}
class Pet<C extends keyof TypeMap> {
    commonName: C;
    animal: TypeMap[C];
    constructor(commonName : C, animal: TypeMap[C]) {
        this.commonName = commonName;
        /*
        //Dropping the parameter and trying to create the object here doesn't work:
        if(commonName === 'cat') {
            this.animal = new Cat();
        } //...
        // because Type 'Cat' is not assignable to type 'Cat & Dog'.
        */
        this.animal = animal;
    }
    makeSound() {
        if(this.commonName === 'cat') {
            //Error: this.animal is of type 'Cat | Dog',
            //not narrowed to Cat as hoped.
            return this.animal.purr();
        } else if (this.commonName === 'dog') {
            //Error: this.animal is of type 'Cat | Dog',
            //not narrowed to Dog as hoped.
            return this.animal.bark();
        }
    }
}
```

The type of restriction shown in `makeSound()` is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish - where you should be able to inspect commonName to learn more about the type of `this.animal` in a way that narrows its type.

A related question about function parameters is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72890232/798371).

Comment: The general issue here is what I call "correlated union types", see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the recommended fix as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is to use a "distributive object type", as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOGVEw). Does that meet your needs and explain the situation? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That looks like a promising strategy, especially with this simple example as posted; thanks!  I'll have to spend more time in the coming days trying to figure out the composability of those to be able to get back to the complexity of the motivating use case (e.g. using one parameter to pick one complex type from a set, then another parameter to pick a member of that set, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The `commonName` and `animal` properties of `Pet` naturally make `Pet` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `commonName` property is the *discriminant*.  Your implementation of `makeSound()` would type check without a problem if `Pet` were such a discriminated union.

The only problem is that `Pet` is [a `class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html), and class instance types need to be definable as [an `interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), and interfaces cannot be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) at all, let alone a discriminated union.

Instead you are trying to represent `Pet` as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  That captures the constraint for `commonName` and `animal` more or less (well, `C` can be a union type itself, and this kind of breaks things, but for *this* situation we will ignore the potential unsoundness.  For our purposes here we can assume that `C` will either be `"cat"` or `"dog"` or any other single member of `keyof TypeMap`).  But the compiler will not allow `makeSound()` to type check.

So we will have to refactor (or pepper things with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress errors, but let's not do that).

---

One potential refactoring is to abstract the check in `makeSound()` to a lookup so that we are not doing case-by-case control flow.  It would look something like this:

```
const petSound = {
    cat: (cat: Cat) => cat.purr(),
    dog: (dog: Dog) => dog.bark()
}

class Pet<C extends keyof TypeMap> {
    makeSound() {
        petSound[this.commonName](this.animal); // error
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler can't follow the correlation between the type of `petSound[this.commonName]` and `this.animal`.  This is the problem I've been calling "correlated unions", as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The fix for this was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves giving `petSound` a *distributive object type* where the compiler can follow the correlation.  It looks like this:

```
const petSound: { [C in keyof TypeMap]: (animal: TypeMap[C]) => void } =
{
    cat: cat => cat.purr(),
    dog: dog => dog.bark()
};
```

Merely by giving `petSound` a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that iterates over `keyof TypeMap`, the above `makeSound()` compiles with no error:

```
class Pet<C extends keyof TypeMap> {
    makeSound() {
        petSound[this.commonName](this.animal); // okay
    }
}
```

Looks good!

(Note that this is still unsound; someone could specify `C` as `keyof TypeMap` and then give a completely wrong `animal` property for a given `commonName` property.  But TypeScript intentionally ignores this unsoundness in order for this correlated union thing to work. See [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730) for more information).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG9oAcCuAnLAKAlCgPQBUAdBSUdAL60BQokMAIgPYDmK0ARmFgGsCxcpWp0a9AJYA7BAFMsAMzDB50ACoBPNPICyYNCnoBIYIgBccRAG5TAE05X2HO5MZsZEJLoQBlNgwZeytUAG1YaFloAXktNiVNHX1DAF0rXDAZKQBbMBArbV0DNAjUwgBeAD5oADc2KXtaaAr6ZFNzBCtOlprOskwcAgAaBydoRy5qic4yPkECeho7RnAoaAAFeQQAHkj5AA8FYJhY+MSilLQa9rM2HJzPADkwHPkrWDsTLNz8wuSSmUvsBPN4sBhgAg2HgQQ9nq93nBhtAfnkCklioYyoRbiYEAALKQQMiwx4yF5vFrQUnwt5fPGE4mo-JU5kgL6SEx5WIBIL2YS43y84JhAlEkn3MkU+SpXBipnZNH4GzQIjUNgCMBaUySSRAA)