# How do I link/join/relate the types of two function parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters, narrowing, type-narrowing

Based on the [similar question about linking class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72887380/798371), how do I get TypeScript to recognize that the value of one parameter to a function (whose value is determined at runtime) restricts the type of another?

Example code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-HZ8nrMo+a0nm1nZAQEFwACYAMwAFgArPh2v5AiEwg4khtEGsymtuYC5YcPgVKmK+wShOEX6bL+uDflsZbciBarLr4kjgPWCjCmWqIZF28gOC+AQQR+0E-n+MFlpsyEHDCpwCBARFvpBDhwZRcYIDRRAOHIy54hEPiaDmNgcdAABuNxAQu4JovwDj+mwDhgOucj0AwQA)):

```js
class Cat { purr() {/*...*/} }
class Dog { bark() {/*...*/} }
interface TypeMap {
    cat: Cat;
    dog: Dog;
}
const makeSound = function<C extends keyof TypeMap>(
    commonName: C,
    animal: TypeMap[C],
) {
    if(commonName === 'cat') {
        //Error: this.animal is of type 'Cat | Dog',
        //not narrowed to Cat as hoped.
        return animal.purr();
    } else if (commonName === 'dog') {
        //Error: this.animal is of type 'Cat | Dog',
        //not narrowed to Dog as hoped.
        return animal.bark();
    }
}
//The intended type-checking is being done in calling contexts:
const caller = function(cat: Cat, dog: Dog) {
    //Error on next line as expected:
    //Argument of type '"dog"' is not assignable
    //to parameter of type '"cat"'.ts(2345)
    makeSound<'cat'>('dog', dog);
    makeSound<'cat'>('cat', dog); //similar error, as expected
    makeSound<'cat'>('cat', cat); //works
    makeSound('cat', cat); //desired style; cat vs. dog not hard-codable
}
```

The TS [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) states 'You can declare a type parameter that is constrained by another type parameter.' but the example given is very simple and seems fragile in terms of ability to generalize to a slightly more complex example like this one.

Comment: Because you are manually checking `commonName` like this, and because `makeSound()`'s return type does not depend on `C`, then the refactoring I'd suggest here is to treat `commonName` and `animal` as elements of a [destructured discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3Pd2W) shows. If that addresses your question, I'll write up an answer explaining. Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: That looks like a promising strategy, especially with this simple example as posted; thanks! I'll have to spend more time in the coming days trying to figure out the composability of those to be able to get back to the complexity of the motivating use case (e.g. using one parameter to pick one complex type from a set, then another parameter to pick a member of that set, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are manually checking `commonName` against individual cases, and TypeScript really doesn't have good support for type checking the body of `makeSound()` if it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  Even though `commonName` is of the generic type `C`, checking `commonName` only [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) the type of `commonName` itself, it does not further constrain `C`.  So unfortunately, even if the compiler knows that `commonName` is `"cat"`, it does not know that `C` is `"cat"`.  It can still be `"cat" | "dog"`, and thus worries about the (admittedly unlikely) possibility of a call like

```
makeSound(
  Math.random() < 0.99 ? "cat" : "dog", 
  Math.random() < 0.99 ? dog : cat
); // no error?!
```

We have failed to actually make the link we intended to make, and even though it's usually good enough (I mean, really, who passes cross-correlated unions into functions like that?), the compiler is unwilling to type check the body.

There are various feature requests asking for an improvement here.  For example, [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) wants to make it possible to say something `C extends oneof keyof TypeMap` so that the full union type `keyof TypeMap` would be rejected.  For now though nothing is implemented, and if we want to write your code we will need to refactor (or else pepper your code with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error... but let's investigate refactoring.)

---

Because the return type of `makeSound()` does not depend on `C`, you can refactor your call signature to a non-generic version that enforces the actual constraint you have.  Essentially the parameter [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), `[commonName, animal]` forms a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the property at index `0` is the *discriminant*, and checking it will narrow the type of the property at index `1`.  You can compute this union type like this:

```
type MakeSoundParam = { [K in keyof TypeMap]:
    [commonName: K, animal: TypeMap[K]]
}[keyof TypeMap];

/* type MakeSoundParam = 
  [commonName: "cat", animal: Cat] | 
  [commonName: "dog", animal: Dog] */
```

TypeScript supports [control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions), which means you can rewrite your function as:

```
const makeSound = function (...[commonName, animal]: MakeSoundParam) {
    if (commonName === 'cat') {
        return animal.purr(); // okay
    } else if (commonName === 'dog') {
        return animal.bark(); // okay
    }
}
```

That compiles without error.  And just to be sure that `makeSound()` still behaves properly from the caller's side:

```
const caller = function (cat: Cat, dog: Dog) {
    makeSound('cat', cat); // ok
    makeSound('dog', dog); // ok
    makeSound('cat', dog); // error
    makeSound('dog', cat); // error
    makeSound(
      Math.random() < 0.99 ? "cat" : "dog", 
      Math.random() < 0.99 ? dog : cat
 ); // error
}
```

Looks good, and even the cross-correlated call is rejected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG9oAcCuAnLAKAlCgPQBUAdBSUdAL60BQokMAIgPYDmK0ARmFgGsCxcpWp0a9AJYA7BAFMsAMzDB50ACoBPNPICyYNCnrRT0YIgBccRAG4TZgCadr7Dvcn0EO9QYHyAZTYMGUcABX4wAFtoAF5uAG0AaWhZaH8tNiVNHwM0AF1LB1ME4DYoqLYZADlo+WskgBpoMBkpKLAQa21dPOT8-PoaBIysnN7DfPt6UmhvXWg-QODQiKxouOhS8sqauusAIgsEA+bW9s7reAR86AAfaAdtiqraqProA+cOU5a2jq60Dctyo9DBZRkECQHX8QRCjgA8mw0DB4koQsAEFIqtAADywaDyAAeClCMFG2R6+kMAD5cMVzDtXvs4I0GecAd1coYErB8mzCKhPBCodAYct4Zt0TJMdiZNBcBQyM9dm95Gd-p1CoswLCVuFIlFBQypNlcGUXnt3nFYvEAOTHO3Gswu6BYeQIbDyjmdMiYHAEWzQIjUNgCMBaBl0eQgCDqU0Ki2quo2+3fJ3GV1md2erDezUgMh8QSB4Oh8ORl2SYVVUUWEAgRRSjFYnHmqw2BDNb6uTjOsziuGhXAOxB25rHfBBkPQMMMwf6kfp7t96fl+e6iXD0cIcfQb5TsuEnBsLAbvXwpecPeTtfHrCn89bxy4AwIAAWZHWoXKwlx0AABjIABOYDoAAfk+Y4DmgQ5vl+N9P2-Zwoj-QCQLAyDvlg8xEEPGdFAfM8XQXeEkRRV9ECQ1oULQoDQIgqDEBguDOAQqivxo39CH-ejMP3TgcNvI8wwjIZ6CAA)